# php SoapServer not print any xml document

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

all

I create a soap server use below code. I found it is a little hard to create wsdl document in PHP .so I decide use non-wsdl mode.

```
 $soapServer = new SoapServer(NULL,array('uri'=>'http://com.test.env',
                                            'encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
    $soapServer->addFunction("workprocess_orders_api_add");
    $soapServer->addFunction("workprocess_list_api_get_local_name");


    $soapServer->handle();
```

but when I try to access this program, it print nothing. both web-browser and program(I use SoapClient)

```
  $client = new SoapClient(NULL,array('uri'=>'http://com.test.env',
                                    'location'=>'http://localhost/~breeze.kay/ams/workprocess/api/soap/',
                                    'trace'=>1,
                                    'style'    => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                                    'use'      => SOAP_LITERAL));


var_dump($client->__call('workprocess_orders_api_add',array())); //print null
var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); //print null
```

I tired call some function like this at client-side:

```
echo $client->sayHello('test');
```

I get error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in /Users/breeze.kay/Sites/ad-test/soap.php:15
```

where is wrong ? I have no idea.:(  the code looks ok. why there is no print?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried it out.

the problem is the request url must append ?wsdl ,like this: http://localhost/wbs/api.php?wsdl

but I use url-rewrite for my sites. the rewrite rule break the original url struct.

by the way, dose somebody know where talk about the url rule for soap request?

I read some manual not find it.

Comment: WSDL generation is not supported yet ... I think I have to use other libary to generate wsdl file

Answer (score 0):

The `XML document not found` error usually occurs when there is an empty space before php opening or after closing tag, try clearing that and test.